# Line integral problem for a surface S

Tags: calculus, integration, vector-analysis

Let $S$ be that part of the surface of the paraboloid $z=x^2+y^2$ between the planes $z=1$ and $z=4$.

Now given $\vec{V}=x^3\hat j+z^3\hat k$ and evaluate the line integrals $\int_{C}{_1}\vec{V}.dr+\int_{C}{_2}\vec{V}.dr$ where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are the curves bounding $S$

I know the answer should be $\frac{45\pi}{4}$ since Let $\vec V=\hat y x^3+\hat z z^3$.  Then, $\nabla \times \vec V=3\hat z x^2$.

A vector point on the surface can be written as $\vec r=\hat \rho\rho +\hat z\rho^2$, where $\hat \rho=\hat x\cos(\phi)+\hat y\sin(\phi)$.

So, the surface element is $\hat n\,dS=\left(\frac{\partial \vec r}{\partial \rho}\times\frac{\partial \vec r}{\partial \phi}\right)\,d\rho\,d\phi=\left(-2\hat\rho\rho^2+ \hat z \rho\right)\,d\rho\,d\phi$.

Therefore,

$$\int_S\nabla\times \vec V\cdot \hat n\,dS=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_1^2 3\rho^3\cos^2(\phi)\,d\rho\,d\phi=45\pi/4$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this circles $dz=0$. The first integral
$$\int_{C_{1}}{x^{3}}dy$$
Let $x=cos(t)$ and $y=sin(t)$ (which indeed parametrizes that circle), then
$$\int_{C_{1}}{x^{3}}dy=\int_{2\pi}^{0}cos^{4}(t)dt=-\frac{3\pi}{4}$$
The second integral is exactly the same except the parametarization is $x=2cos(t)$ and $y=2\sin(t)$
$$\int_{C}{x^{3}}dy=\int_{C_{1}}{x^{3}}dy+\int_{C_{2}}{x^{3}}dy=\int_{2\pi}^{0}cos^{4}(t)dt+16\int_{0}^{2\pi}cos^{4}(t)dt$$

$$\int_{C}{x^{3}}dy=15\int_{0}^{2\pi}cos^{4}(t)dt=\frac{45\pi}{4}$$

Comment: i first evaluated the surface integral $\iint_S \nabla \times V.ndS$  and calculated it as $\frac{45\pi}{4}$ and i'm assuming if the surface integral is equal to this then it is safe to say that the line integrals should also turn out to be $\frac{45\pi}{4}$ due to stokes' theorem.

Comment: should it be $cos^3(t)$ since it is $x^3$?

Comment: No, you have $dy=cos{(t)}dt$, so $x^{3}dy=cos^4(t)dt$

Comment: oh okay, could you maybe evaluate the surface integral, because if i've made a mistake somewhere  i dont understand where.

Comment: I still get 51. Maybe show your solution?

Comment: Let $\vec V=\hat j x^3+\hat k z^3$.  Then, $\nabla \times \vec V=3\hat k x^2$.  

A vector point on the surface can be written as $\vec r=\hat \rho\rho +\hat z\rho^2$, where $\hat \rho=\hat x\cos(\phi)+\hat y\sin(\phi)$.  

So, the surface element is $\hat n\,dS=\left(\frac{\partial \vec r}{\partial \rho}\times\frac{\partial \vec r}{\partial \phi}\right)\,d\rho\,d\phi=\left(-2\hat\rho\rho^2+ \hat z \rho\right)\,d\rho\,d\phi$.

Therefore, 

$$\int_S\nabla\times \vec V\cdot \hat n\,dS=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_1^2 3\rho^3\cos^2(\phi)\,d\rho\,d\phi=45\pi/4$$

Comment: maybe i went wrong when trying to paramatise?

Comment: the surface element is $1/2r^{2}d\phi$ as u can see by sine theorem?

Comment: https://www.symbolab.com/solver/double-integrals-calculator/%5Cint_%7B1%7D%5E%7B2%7D%20%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B2%5Cpi%7D%203r%5E%7B3%7Dcos%5E%7B2%7D%5Cleft(%5Ctheta%5Cright)d%5Ctheta%20dr

Comment: i've figured it out the first circle is going anti clock wise, thus we take away $\frac{3\pi}{4}$ so the integral is $15\int_{C_{1}}x^3dy$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_C \textbf{V} \ d\textbf{r} = \int_{a}^b \left(\textbf{V} \circ \gamma\right)(t) \cdot \gamma'(t) \ dt$$

where $\gamma: I \to \mathbb{R}^n$ parametrizes $C$ on $[a,b]$. All you have to do is parametrize the curve given by $x^2+y^2 = 1$ and $x^2+y^2 = 4$ which are circles.

Comment: could we let $x=rcos(\theta)$  and $y=rsin(\theta)$

Comment: Yes. You can use that parametrization, but you have to add a $z$-coordinate which gives the location of the circle.

Comment: so could we set $z=r$ which would be the radius's of each circle?

Comment: If you let $z = r$ then you are giving coordinates on the cone. You need to let $z$ be the height in which you took the intersection to get the curve (circle).

Comment: so what about $z=r^2cos\theta sin\theta$

Comment: Your circle arose by taking intersections of planes at height $1,4$ with your surfaces. So what should the heights of the circles be? i.e what should the $z$-coordinate be? It's not a function, it should be a constant.

Comment: ahh okay so should it be $4$ and $1$ i was thinking that $r$ was equal to the radius of the circle and not the cone, my mistake.

Comment: Yup! That is correct. I'm glad you figured it out by yourself. I think that way is more rewarding.

Comment: Also, for the sake of closing the problem, accept any one of these two answers if you are finished with your problem.

Comment: I would but I'm unsure now as when evaluating these I don't get the same answer as the surface intergrals can you check if it's done correctly I've added it to my question

Comment: ur Stokes have given ur the wrong result, (i guess) cause u have chosen the wrong orientation of the normal.

Comment: @KirylPesotski could you provide a solution?

Comment: i dont understand what you mean by that i'm unsure where i'm going wrong..